# How to add a k value to the SelfQueryRetriever of langchain

Tags: py-langchain

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5hqD.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qs3o.png)
It is mentioned in the langchain document.We can also use the self query retriever to specify k: the number of documents to fetch.

We can do this by passing enable_limit=True to the constructor.
but the parameter k is not accepted,Wish someone could help me

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5nch.png)
I tried to give a value of k

Comment: Someone has answered this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76954499/4757432

Answer (score 0):

To define a *SelfQueryRetriever* in LangChain that gives an output of *k-values* you need to use the `search_kwargs`  parameter.

The following code gives a response with 2 documents:

```python
from langchain.llms import BaseLanguageModel
from langchain.vectorstores import VectorStore
from langchain.retrievers import SelfQueryRetriever

self_query_retriever = SelfQueryRetriever(
    vectorstore=my_vector_store, structured_query_translator=my_structured_query_translator,  # Define this too
    search_type='similarity',
    search_kwargs={'k': 2}
)
```