# Self-querying retrieval in langchain returning only 4 results

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, data-science, langchain

I want all the articles related to specific tag example sustainability from documents. But it is only returing me Four articles. There are total 7 articles related to sustainability in vectorstore out of 20 articles.

Here is my code:

```
import pinecone
from langchain.schema import Document
from langchain.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain.vectorstores import Pinecone
import os
from langchain.llms import OpenAI
from langchain.retrievers.self_query.base import SelfQueryRetriever
from langchain.chains.query_constructor.base import AttributeInfo


pinecone_api_key = "xxxxxxxx"
pinecone_env = "xxxxxxxxxx"
# pinecone.init(api_key=os.environ["PINECONE_API_KEY"], environment=os.environ["PINECONE_ENV"])
pinecone.init(api_key=pinecone_api_key, environment=pinecone_env)

embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings()

index_name="langchain-self-retriever-ppo"
index = pinecone.Index(index_name)
text_field = "text"

# vectorstore = Pinecone.from_documents(
#     docs, embeddings, index_name="langchain-self-retriever-demo"
# )

vectorstore = Pinecone(
    index, embeddings.embed_query, text_field
)

metadata_field_info=[
    AttributeInfo(
        name="headline",
        description="The headline of the news article", 
        type="string or list[string]", 
    ),
    AttributeInfo(
        name="date",
        description="The date, news article was published", 
        type="integer", 
    ),
    AttributeInfo(
        name="publication",
        description="The name of the publication which published this news article", 
        type="string", 
    ),
    AttributeInfo(
        name="domain",
        description="The domain of the news article",
        type="float"
    ),
]
document_content_description = "Brief summary of a news article"
llm = OpenAI(temperature=0)
# retriever = SelfQueryRetriever.from_llm(llm, vectorstore, document_content_description, metadata_field_info, verbose=True)

retriever = SelfQueryRetriever.from_llm(
    llm, 
    vectorstore, 
    document_content_description, 
    metadata_field_info, 
    enable_limit=True,
    verbose=True
)

# This example only specifies a relevant query
retrieved_docs = retriever.get_relevant_documents("Articles which are related to sustainability")
print(retrieved_docs)
print(len(retrieved_docs))
```

I have gone inside `get_relevant_documents` method here it uses `self.vectorstore.search` which calls `self.similarity_search` method which by defaults sets limit to 4 if not given.

I tried setting limit to 7 it returned 7 `sustainability` articles.
But I wouldn't know how much articles will be related to `sustainability` so I can't by default set the limit.

Comment: Im running into the exact same thing...it's always 4

Answer (score 2):

Add `search_kwargs={"k": k}` as an argument to the retriever class and replace k with the desired number of results.

Comment: thank you for your reply.
However, I don't have a specific number, i.e., 'k'. There will be any number of articles related to the topic.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to change the retriever method to "similarity_score_threshold" as described on the [Langchain site](https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/data_connection/retrievers/vectorstore#similarity-score-threshold-retrieval), e.g.:

```
retriever = db.as_retriever(search_type="similarity_score_threshold", search_kwargs={"score_threshold": 0.5})
```

You still need to adjust the "k" argument if you do this. Otherwise, I found that it still defaults to k=4 max documents returned. As a workaround, I set "k" to the length of the full set of documents so that it returns every document above the "score_threshold", e.g.:

```
retriever = db.as_retriever(search_type="similarity_score_threshold", search_kwargs={"score_threshold": 0.7, "k": len(docs)})
```

The downside is that this requires experimenting with score thresholds, which is an inexact science.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Chroma for my vectorstore and faced similar problems. This was how I solved it. Note: I named my vectorstore as `db`.

```py
persist_directory = 'db'

# Only run these 2 lines for the first run. Comment them out after running it for the first time.
db = Chroma.from_documents(doc, OpenAIEmbeddings(), persist_directory=persist_directory)
db.persist()

# Subsequent runs should give the specified number of documents
db = Chroma(persist_directory=persist_directory, embedding_function=OpenAIEmbeddings())

document_content_description = "Your document description"
retriever = SelfQueryRetriever.from_llm(
    llm,
    db,
    document_content_description,
    metadata_field_info,
    verbose=True,
    enable_limit=True
)

docs = retriever.get_relevant_documents("I am looking for 7 documents regarding...") # Should return 7 documents
print(len(docs)) # Should be 7
```

Hope this helps.